# Why does dataframe.appy cost too much time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe ‘df_ret_temp’

[image]

[image]
I want to set the column accMonth values.
There are codes run fast

```
df_ret_temp.loc[df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]<='03','accMonth']=df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[0:4].apply(lambda x:str(int(x)-1))+'12'
df_ret_temp.loc[(df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]<='06') &
                (df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]>'03'),'accMonth']=df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[0:4]+'03'

df_ret_temp.loc[(df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]<='09') &
                (df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]>'06'),'accMonth']=df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[0:4]+'06'

df_ret_temp.loc[(df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]<='12') &
                (df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[5:7]>'09'),'accMonth']=df_ret_temp['tradeDate'].str[0:4]+'09'
```

However,when I use apply function to set the column accMonth values.The codes cost too much time.

```
def df_ret_tempFun(row):
    if row['tradeDate'][5:7]<='03':
        row['accMonth']=str(int(row['tradeDate'][0:4])-1)+'12'
    elif row['tradeDate'][5:7]<='06' and row['tradeDate'][5:7]>'03':
        row['accMonth']=row['tradeDate'][0:4]+'03'
    elif row['tradeDate'][5:7]<='09' and row['tradeDate'][5:7]>'06':
        row['accMonth']=row['tradeDate'][0:4]+'06'
    else:
         row['accMonth']=row['tradeDate'][0:4]+'09'
    return row
df_ret_temp=df_ret_temp.apply(df_ret_tempFun,axis=1)
```

why does the apply function have lower performance.

Answer (score 2):

`.apply(..., axis=1)` is a `for x in df.iter*` loop under the hood, so it's not vectorized and therefore is **very** slow.

But your question is a very good example of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Here is a Pandas solution for your "not asked" ;-) question:

```
In [33]: x
Out[33]:
         Date
0  2007-01-01
1  2007-04-02
2  2007-08-03
3  2007-11-04

In [34]: x.dtypes
Out[34]:
Date    object
dtype: object
```

first make sure your `Date` column is of `datetime` dtype:

```
In [35]: x.Date = pd.to_datetime(x.Date)

In [36]: x.dtypes
Out[36]:
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Vectorized solution:

```
In [37]: x['accMonth'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.PeriodIndex(df.Date, freq='Q') - 1, freq='3M')

In [38]: x
Out[38]:
        Date accMonth
0 2007-01-01  2006-12
1 2007-04-02  2007-03
2 2007-08-03  2007-06
3 2007-11-04  2007-09
```